# Why does my Django form keep saying "this field is required"

Tags: django, django-forms

Does anyone know why my form (filepicker) is constantly returning "this field is required" when it worked in a simpler version?

My view is

```
def add_attempt(request, m_id, a_id):
    template = loader.get_template('add_attempt.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import pprint 
        pprint.pprint(request.POST)
        pprint.pprint(request.FILES)
        form = UploadAttemptForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            form.instance.user_id = request.user
            form.instance.assignment = m.Assignment.objects.get(id=a_id)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('assignment', args=(m_id, a_id)))
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = UploadAttemptForm()
    context = RequestContext(request, 
        {
        'form':form,
        })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

My Model is

```
class Attempt(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pdf_filename = models.FileField(storage=settings.S3_STORAGE, upload_to='pdfs')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date uploaded')
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
```

And my form is

```
class UploadAttemptForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadAttemptForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta():
        model = Attempt
        fields = ['pdf_filename',]
```

The error prints out as

```
`<QueryDict: {u'submit': [u'Upload Attempt'], u'pdf_filename': [u'something.pdf']}>`
```

`<MultiValueDict: {}>`
    `<ul class="errorlist"><li>pdf_filename<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: Have you added the ``enctype= multipart/form-data`` to your ``<form>`` element in your template ? If you don't have this  element your ``request.FILES`` will always be empty.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks a million. Sadly as I didn't fully understand how the forms were working in Django I didn't spot that. Thanks again and if you want to make that a full answer I'll accept that.

Comment: Cool! I added a proper answer. I'd used a comment in the first place because I hadn't actually seen your template (however forgetting ``enctype`` is a common error, it has bitten me one or two times also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding my comment as a proper answer:

Please try adding `enctype= multipart/form-data` to your `<form>` element in your template file.

If you don't have this element your `request.FILES` will always be empty.

Copying from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads:

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

If the field is required in your `models.py` (i.e. you have not stated `blank=True` or `null=True`), and you are using a `ModelForm`, then that will be a required field in your `ModelForm`