# How to create a table of update forms in Django

Tags: django

I want the ability to update records in a table format so that I can quickly make updates. I am close to figuring this out, but `form.valid()` is still returning `False`.

My model:

```
class Actions(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now, editable = False)
    dateComplete = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    action = models.TextField(max_length=1000,)
    responsibility = models.ForeignKey(staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null = True,)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

My view:

```
def actionItemsView(request):
    ActionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Actions, fields=('action', 'responsibility','complete','meeting','dateComplete'),max_num=1)
    if request.method == "POST":
        action_formset = ActionFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,queryset=Actions.objects.filter())
        for action_form in action_formset:
            print(action_form.errors)
            if action_form.is_valid():
                action = action_form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/saved!/')
    else:
        formset = ActionFormSet(queryset=Actions.objects.filter(complete = False))
        return render(request, 'action_items.html', {'formset': formset})
```

My template:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
  <tr>
    <th>decision</th>
    <th>responsibility</th>
    <th>complete?</th>
    <th>meeting</th>
    <th>date complete</th>
    <th>submit</th>
  </tr>

{%for form in formset%}
<form method="post" enctype= multipart/form-data>
  <tr>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <td>{{ form.action }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.responsibility }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.complete }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.meeting }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.dateComplete }}</td>
    <td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

When I run this, the template is rendered exactly how I would expect, but when I make any changes to an item and hit submit, it throws `The view meetings.views.actionItemsView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`
Because form.valid() is False

`form.errors` is returning:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>action<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>meeting<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>action<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>meeting<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

But I can see in the template that each record has a meeting assigned to it in the dropdown...

Answer (score 1):

> The view meetings.views.actionItemsView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Given this is the error, it's saying that you are not returning any `HTTPRESPONSE`, which is true since you don't have any return statements if it's a `POST` request.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    action_formset = ActionFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,queryset=Actions.objects.filter())
    for action_form in action_formset:
        print(action_form.errors)
        if action_form.is_valid():
            action = action_form.save()
```

All methods in `views.py` are required to return an `HTTPRESPONSE`, so simply try to add any kind of `HTTP` response in there and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I was really hoping you were right, as you were correct I did not have a response for POST. However this still did not fix the issue, as `if action_form.is_valid():` returns `False`. So the form is not updating or doing anything...

Comment: Ahh, I see. It seems like the error is coming as a result of some fields being empty; as shown by the `form.errors`. I can't tell which fields they are but you would have to state `blank=True` or `null=True` for those fields in the models. Have you also migrated your models?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841054/why-does-my-django-form-keep-saying-this-field-is-required) for a similar problem